# Run Docker as rootless mode

Tags: docker

I am trying to run a docker as a rootless mode in ubuntu VM.

1. I am provisioning the VM using the terraform script.
2. I am using the terraform run module to execute commands and prerequisites.
3. but when I have added docker as rootless mode commands in this run module those scripts are not executing even though I switch the new user. 
   Below are the commands I need to execute as another user in the terraform run module.

```bash
sudo apt-get install -y uidmap
curl -fsSL https://get.docker.com/rootless | sh
export DOCKER_HOST=unix:///run/user/1000/docker.sock
systemctl --user status docker
```

4. I am getting an error as Refusing to install rootless Docker as the root user
5. My goal is to automate this using a terraform run module.

should any could help to solve this issue or is there any other workaround for this.

Thanks in Advance.

I have tried with switch user and execute but still, these commands are not executing.

```bash
sudo apt-get install -y uidmap
curl -fsSL https://get.docker.com/rootless | sh
export DOCKER_HOST=unix:///run/user/1000/docker.sock
systemctl --user status docker
```

I would like to automate this using a terraform run module or any other way but the only thing is this should be executed once VM is provision.

Answer (score -3):

Read the script https://get.docker.com/rootless where it says **"This script should be run with an unprivileged user and install/setup Docker under $HOME/bin/"**

If you do still want to install it then you just need to learn how to read shell scripts as there is this part in the script:

```
# User verification: deny running as root (unless forced?)
if [ "$(id -u)" = "0" ] && [ -z "$FORCE_ROOTLESS_INSTALL" ]; then
    >&2 echo "Refusing to install rootless Docker as the root user"; exit 1
fi
```